# Telling whether a date is before a particular time in excel

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet with a date column in Column A. I want to have a column where it returns TRUE if the date is before September 2016. How do I do that?

I tried this code in Excel but it wouldn't work.

```
=if(A1="2017","TRUE",if(month(F1)<"September,"FALSE","TRUE"))
```

Can anyone help me correcting this one? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming Column A has the actual dates (ex: 3/3/2017). So your if statement (if<"September") is trying to compare text against a date, which will give you an error.

Easiest way to do this is enter 9/30/2016 in a separate cell (for this example, say Q1). Then in your formula, simply use:=A1 < $Q$1 and drag that down. It should give you T/F for the dates.

Answer (score 0):

If `Column A` is formatted as a date, it has to be compared with a date only. If not excel will give you unexpected results.

The `DATE` function in excel allows you to input data in date format with `Years, Months and Days`. The format is below,

`=DATE(Years,Months,Days)`

You can try the below formula,

`=A1<DATE(2016,9,30)`

and drag it down throughout the range.

[image]